# IMA roles for system accounts

Tags: identity-management

How to create IAM roles with AIS permission boundary for system accounts?

1. Can a system account assume multiple such IAM roles in 1 AWS Account?
2. If an IAM role is created in account 1 but shared with account 2. A trusted principal. Can such a role be assumed by a bot in account 2?

Answer (score 0):

Can a system account assume multiple such IAM roles in 1 AWS Account?
A:) System account to be granted SCP custom_role and in the assume role trust-relationship add the system account Masscot ID to achieve.
If an IAM role is created in account 1 but shared with account 2. A trusted principal. Can such a role be assumed by a bot in account 2?
A:)Yes can be achieived through granting role switch from account 1 to account 2.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).